# Background of the TextBlock should be in red when Amount is < 0 in WindowsPhone

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

Basically i bind the Amount to the TextBlock in the Windows Phone when Amount is negative i should change the Background color to Red.

Can we achieve this through xaml with 0 % c# code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock ... Background="{Binding Amount, Converter={StaticResource AmountToBackgroundBrushConverter}" />
```

Just craft your own AmountToBackgroundBrushConverter